# C# extension method can't be unqualified with using static

Tags: c#, extension-methods, using, using-statement, c#-7.0

I've found a limitation when it comes to use *extension methods* with `using static`.

Check the following code snippet:

```
// file: A.cs
namespace Test.A
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
         public static int sum(this int source, int number) => source + number;
    }
}

// file: Program.cs
using static Test.A.Extensions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
             sum(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

`sum(0, 10)` won't work even when it has been imported with `using static`: the compiler says that `sum` doesn't exist in the whole context.

Is there any workaround for this as of C# 7.1 which may not involve a non-extension method overload to `sum`?

Comment: What is sum2? You have an extension called sum

Comment: @Steve Fixed... it was a typo

Comment: @LeonBarkan Calm! I've already fixed this typo :D

Comment: And in any case calling sum has no effect at all because it doesn't return the result of the operation

Comment: @Steve Are you sure about this? :D

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks ;) I've already voted to close, the other Q&A is enough.

Comment: @Steve BTW, `sum` it returns something, this the way expression-bodied methods are implemented since C# 6

Comment: I have used the wrong word _return_, I mean _sum(0, 10);_ has no effect because the code doesn't assign a variable or write _the return_ out somewhere.

Comment: @Steve I see, BTW it was just a code snippet to understand the issue